# Zuul Gateway - setSendZuulResponse & removeRouteHost

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

Just wanted some clarification - within Netflix's Zuul Gateway, the RequestContext object has two methods, setSendZuulResponse and removeRouteHost.

First, can somebody tell me the difference between the two. From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180375/using-zuul-as-an-authentication-gateway), they do the same but I can't find documentation that describes these ([sendZuulResponse](http://netflix.github.io/zuul/javadoc/zuul-core/com/netflix/zuul/context/RequestContext.html#sendZuulResponse()) and [removeRouteHost](http://netflix.github.io/zuul/javadoc/zuul-core/com/netflix/zuul/context/RequestContext.html#removeRouteHost())).

Second, does the Zuul filter hit the resource/origin server regardless of being filtered but just hides the response to the client? Based on the documentation for [sendZuulResponse](http://netflix.github.io/zuul/javadoc/zuul-core/com/netflix/zuul/context/RequestContext.html#sendZuulResponse()), it says:

```
"If this value if true then the response should be sent to the client."
```

My rationale is, if this value is set to false, then the response should not* be sent to the client; However, Zuul has the response(???), which means that it had sent the request anyways (if that makes sense).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul dependency, then the [SimpleHostRoutingFilter](https://github.com/ykkxdu/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/route/SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java) class, which is the one that makes the downstream call, only gets activated when the following code is met

```
RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRouteHost() != null && RequestContext.getCurrentContext().sendZuulResponse();
```

From that we can see that if either the route host is null or if the Zuul response is set to false, the filter won't run and a request to the downstream service won't be made.