# Spring boot Zuul Authorization header interceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, netflix-zuul

I've created a SpringBoot application my `Application.java` looks like following

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return new UiConfiguration("validatorUrl", "list", "alpha", "schema",
            UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS, false, true, 60000L);
    }
}
```

When someone calls any API via Gateway, it has authorization header `Authorization: bearer: <token>` like this. Now, I need to validate this JWT token.

How do I validate every request for valid JWT token and if incorrect send unauthorized?

Comment: Is this not the same issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180375/using-zuul-as-an-authentication-gateway

Comment: @PärNilsson you are right. My bad.